# Rendering results with alpha blending on Metal are not as expected

Tags: ios, swift, metal

I would like to do off-screen rendering with Metal and use alpha Blending etc. to make it look like a completed drawing.
I hope that the program can be reproduced with Metal by porting what was made on OpenGL once.
[image]

Pipeline during off-screen rendering

```
renderToTextureRenderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments [0] .clearColor = MTLClearColor (red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.0)
```

[image]

In the current state of, the surroundings have turned black,

```
 MTLClearColor (red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 0.0)
```

It's natural, but the whole thing turns white,

With `MTLClearColor (red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5, alpha: 0.0)`, both are in the middle, and the color comes out, but it is far from what I imagined.

Even if it does not clearColor, it is the same and I think that this part is not the root cause, and I think that it is a problem of Shader itself or a problem of description in Pipeline of the final Rendering at the time of alpha blending.
One of the problems is that `gl.clearColor (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);` in OpenGL at the time of final rendering has not been realized. I was wondering if it could be done like Apple's Developer page, but it wasn't successful.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metalkit/mtkview/1536036-clearcolor

Shader is not special, it uses the circle of the distance function as alpha, and it is pasted as a texture at alpha blending and final rendering.

I don't want an easy method like rendering with a red circle on a white background because I value the result of alpha blending.

We have made it possible to download the actual code, which is a current sample. The URL is as follows.
https://sgaworks.com/code/MetalCodeSample.zip

Answer (score 0):

Your `MTKView` is opaque. You are writing out a proper alpha value to the texture, but since your view is opaque, compositor just discards alpha and shows the RGB texture.

You can make your view transparent by setting `isOpaque` to `false`. This will force compositor to blend your drawable with whatever is going to be underneath it.

This is the image I'm getting by just setting `mtkView.isOpaque = false` with dark mode on: [image: screenshot]

And this one is with dark mode off:
[image]

Comment: thank you. To View Controller
`mtkView.device = mtlDevice
mtkView.framebufferOnly = true
mtkView.isOpaque = false`
I wrote it, but the result is that the background does not become a white background but remains a black background. Am I still missing something?

Comment: You need a view underneath it or a background color. For example, you can see in my screenshot, that the color isn't black, but rather gray. It's because I have dark mode on, if I turn dark mode off, it's going to have the system white color underneath. I've updated answer to include the screenshot. I'm not well-versed in `UIKit` or `AppKit` specifics beyond the `CAMetalLayer` so I don't have a more specific answer.

Comment: I'm running it on an actual iPhone, and dark mode is off from the beginning. If you execute the sample code as it is, it will be a red circle on a black background in the screenshot attached to the question text, and you will be aiming for a red circle on a white background. Should `mtkView` have a separate background color?

Comment: I don't think background color works on `MTKView`. I think in your case you can just chose a clear color for the drawable texture the "background" color you want it to be.

Comment: I think it's the method you taught me about transparency, but how do you change the background color? Should I use `CAMetalLayer` instead of `MTKView`?

Comment: When I checked it on the actual Mac, the result was the same as JustSomeGuy. However, the result seems to be different on the actual iPhone. The background cannot be changed from black at all. If possible, try it on your iPhone. Also, please give me some advice.

Comment: As I said, `MTKView` doesn't have a background. If you make it opaque, system compositor will just blend it with whatever is underneath it. On macOS, there happens to be a default background somewhere in the view hierarchy, presumably, but you can probably disable it by making window itself opaque. On iOS, there's nothing underneath your app itself, so the color is black. And as I said before, you need to put another view underneath it that has actual color so that compositor can blend the two together. And by view I mean a `UIView` or an `NSView` that is different from your `MTKView`

Comment: On the background side`self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white`However, it seems that the background remains black. The mtkView side also tries to change the color, but I'm still worried.

Comment: What is `self.view`. The `backgroundColor` in `MTKView` won't work.

Comment: I'm sorry! The problem has been resolved. Apparently he overlooked a completely different issue. The problem was that when porting to Metal, I made Alpha Blending in the state of OpenGL. I'm sorry for your precious time.